# parameter in POST request not appearing in kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-custom-manager

I have a custom manager that creates an object from a POST request. The issue is that the 2 manytomany parameters aren't passing any info.

Here is the method (in a custom manager)

```
class ConditionManager(models.Manager):
use_in_migrations = True
use_for_related_fields=True

def create_condition(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    for i in kwargs:
        print i, kwargs[i]
    condition_obj = conditions.models.Condition(name=kwargs['name'], contagious=kwargs['contagious'], treatable=kwargs['treatable'], treatment=kwargs['treatment'], severeity=kwargs['severeity'], symptoms=kwargs['symptoms'], speciality=kwargs['speciality'])

    condition_obj.save()
    return condition_obj
```

Here is the serializer

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  symptoms = SymptomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

  def create(self, validated_data):
attrs = validated_data
request = self.context['request']
return Condition.new.create_condition(**attrs)

 class Meta:
model = Condition
fields = ('id', 'treatment', 'name', 'contagious', 'treatable', 'treatment', 'severeity', 'symptoms')
```

Here is the POST request

[POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYijh.png)

Here is the log

> ()
>   treatable True
>   name epilepsy
>   treatment 1
>   contagious False
>   severeity 7
>   Internal Server Error: /conditions/new/condition/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/prashantcraju/medicalrecords/conditions/views.py", line 20, in create_condition
>       serializer.save()
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
>       self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
>     File "/Users/prashantcraju/medicalrecords/conditions/serializers.py", line 21, in create
>       return Condition.new.create_condition(**attrs)
>     File "/Users/prashantcraju/medicalrecords/conditions/managers.py", line 20, in create_condition
>       condition_obj = conditions.models.Condition(name=kwargs['name'], contagious=kwargs['contagious'], treatable=kwargs['treatable'], treatment=kwargs['treatment'], severeity=kwargs['severeity'], symptoms=kwargs['symptoms'], speciality=kwargs['speciality'])
>   KeyError: 'symptoms'
>   [19/Feb/2017 20:51:11] "POST /conditions/new/condition/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14989

As you can see, the 2 manytomany field aren't even showing up in the log.

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you passing kwargs when you do so?

Comment: Looking at the tracback, you at least need to show us your serializer.

Comment: updated with the full Manager and the Serialzer